# Is there an API for the built-in Windows 8 "Modern reader" PDF Viewer?

Tags: pdf, windows-8

Windows 8 will include a built-in PDF reader called "Modern Reader". In our current application, we embed the Adobe Reader as an ActiveX control.

Can I embed Windows 8 "Modern Reader" in a similar way?

Comment: i'd love to know the answer to this too. really good question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Windows 8.1 has APIs for rendering PDFs. Please have a look at the [Windows.Data.Pdf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.data.pdf.aspx) namespace

Build conference session recording available on [Channel 9](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2013/3-175). This details how to use the new PDF rendering APIs.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please summarise the links in your answer; that way, if they go stale the answer won't be completely useless.

Answer (score 9):

The answer to your question is 'no'. There are (at this time) no published api's for the Modern Reader PDF viewer. The next best thing is the PDF-Tools.com solution which I think might be too generic in it's approach to meet your needs but is still worth checking out.

See: http://www.pdf-tools.com/public/downloads/manuals/vwra.pdf

Sorry to bear bad news. Just don't shoot the messenger :)

Comment: I asked Microsoft explicitly about this and they confirmed in this forum post there is no api available:  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/fcbfac40-1543-4595-9f84-90641fc0e594

Comment: The PDF-Tools.com PDF doesn't mention Windows Store or WinRT, so it looks like it's not relevant here.

Answer (score 3):

You can open the PDF file in Windows Reader from your application. This will open the Windows Reader separately.

```
  StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri(filePath));
  Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(file);
```

filePath is the path to the PDF file.

Answer (score 3):

here is a code example on how to render a PDF document into BitmapImages:

```
private async Task<List<BitmapImage>> LoadPdf()
{
var _pageImages = new List<BitmapImage>();

// Open the file
var file = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync("demo.pdf");

// Create PDF document
var pdfDocument = await PdfDocument.LoadFromFileAsync(file);

// Loop through the pages
for (uint i = 0; i < pdfDocument.PageCount; i++)
{
    using (var stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
    {
        using (var page = pdfDocument.GetPage(i))
        {
            // Set render options
            var renderOptions = new PdfPageRenderOptions
                                        {
                                            BackgroundColor = Colors.LightGray,
                                            DestinationHeight = (uint)(page.Size.Height * 10)
                                        };

            // Render into bitmap image
            await page.RenderToStreamAsync(stream, renderOptions);
            var image = new BitmapImage();
            await image.SetSourceAsync(stream);
            await stream.FlushAsync();
            _pageImages.Add(image);
        }
    }
}

return _pageImages;
}
```

Original Source: http://www.win8tutorial.net/windows-8-1/render-pdf-documents/

Greetings
Christian

Answer (score 1):

I have GREAT news. Look what I found: [Reading PDF and XPS on your Windows 8 application using WinRT](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eternalcoding/archive/2013/04/15/reading-pdf-and-xps-on-your-windows-8-application-using-winrt.aspx)

[David Catuhe](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/david%20catuhe/) posted it on Msdn Blog:

> PDF and XPS file formats are widely used across the world and you
>   could need one day to display them inside your application.
>  Today
>   I would like to share with you a simple way to do so by using an open
>   source solution: MuPDF (a multiplatform lightweight PDF and XPS
>   viewer).
>   The result is a simple but really useful Windows 8 Modern UI app that
>   is able to display a PDF/XPS file.

Hope it's help everyone!

Comment: +1 Certainly useful, but muPdf is GPL, isn't it? So we won't be able to use it in closed source applications.

Answer (score 1):

PDF Rendering in Store apps has become really easy with Windows 8.1.

Windows 8.1 now has PDF rendering APIs and ability to save/show PDF pages as images. Check out [these samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/PDF-viewer-sample-85a4bb30).

Answer (score 0):

take a look here ... [http://social.msdn.microsoft.com](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-BZ/winappswithhtml5/thread/0c578435-e246-48a2-b5cd-d19fd389fa84)

cause there are **no apis available** you can use the following javascript framework to integrate your pdf to metro style html5 apps

https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js

Answer (score 0):

**Modern PDF Reader** is no longer included in the final release of Microsoft Windows 8. I use [Cool PDF Reader](http://www.pdf2exe.com/reader.html) as an alternative to the Modern PDF Reader. Windows 8 does come with a Reader App in Metro Style, crippled in functionality, especially since it does not allow you to print PDFs. Cool PDF Reader is a nice Windows desktop application to open, view, and even print PDF document.