# Looking for a PDF Writer for Windows 8 Metro Apps

Tags: c#, pdf, windows-8, pdf-generation

I'm creating a Windows 8/Metro App and am looking for a library that can generate PDF documents programmatically (that can either be printed or emailed by the user).

I've found some C# libraries for PDF writing (http://itextpdf.com/ for example) but I've been unable to get them to work in Windows 8.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What problems have you run into with the libraries you have found?

Comment: The libraries I've tried use System.IO.FileStream to create the file, but FileStream does not seem to be part of System.IO in Windows 8. Perhaps there is an equivalent in Windows.Storage but I'm having a difficult time getting it to work.

Comment: Can you use online REST API? If yes then try this http://www.convertapi.com

Comment: @Tomas - looks like a nice tool and I may look into it for another project, but I need to be able to have this App run while not connected to the Internet.

Comment: I found solution. Check my [SO Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16794384/1616443)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After an exhausting search, I've found the answer to my own question: **Siberix Report Writer** ([www.siberix.com](http://www.siberix.com)).  They have versions for .NET, Silverlight, Mono for Android, *AND* for Windows Store.  The binaries are only $199 ($3500 if you want source).

It is very easy to wrap into your application, comes with great code examples, and the technical customer service is very quick and helpful (thank you Victor).

One of the best third party products I've seen in a long time.

Comment: Now $750 per platform.

Answer (score 0):

There are some paid pdf libraries for WinRT but nothing free yet.

Answer (score 0):

[ComponentOne](http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/PDFWinRT/) has now released their .NET PDF library for Windows Runtime.

Comment: Looks like they have some nice tools...$895 for the PDF tool alone (ouch!).  As an update, we've been very happy with Siberix...even purchased the .NET version and are converting our .NET clients from TallPDF to Siberix.

Answer (score 0):

meanwhile there are quite a few libraries that support Pdf generation. You'll find a good overview in [Mike Taulty's Blog](http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2013/04/23/annotating-pdf-documents-in-a-windows-8-store-app.aspx).

However, I ran into issues when I was trying to annotate existing Pdfs. The existing libraries capable of (transparent) annotations are quite pricy. Therefore, I ended up annotating the Pdf on the server side.

Feel free to read more about my experience at [Mils](https://milsapp.com/blog/pdf-manipulation-on-windows-8)'s blog.