# How to Generate a PDF in Metro app?

Tags: c#, xaml, pdf, microsoft-metro, pdf-generation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Looking for a PDF Writer for Windows 8 Metro Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11109427/looking-for-a-pdf-writer-for-windows-8-metro-apps)

I wanted to know how to generate a PDF in my Metro App.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would either to use html templates and a html-to-pdf (ex. EO.PDF) converter or xaml templates that get converted into xps and then use a xps-to-pdf converter (ex. ABCPDF).

There are other alternatives such as ITextSharp that allow you to programmatically create a pdf via some builder objects.

What you have to realize is that PDF is not markup based. Every letter written to PDF ends up at a specific x/y co-ordinate - PDF is designed for design work/print. A simple concept of a word in a markup tag is easy to interpret, meanwhile in PDF there only way to know a few letters form a word is via a proximity-based word classification algorithm.

Unfortunately, if you want to use PDF commercially, you can expect to pay for it. Another alternative is giving your users a print option and have them use a PDF printer (which basically makes an image per page and saves it to a PDF file) - I've heard of the PDF-print solution being automated and used on the web.

I'd probably go for the XPS and XPS-To-PDF route for a Metro app.

Comment: I have added all the dll's required for iTestSharp in my metro app but it says Could not load file or assembly 'System.Drawing', Please help me out how can i resolve this ???????????

Comment: This cant be resolved as in metro application a lot of namespaces have been removed