# trouble in windows8 metrostyle app pdfviewer( using c1pdfviewer)

Tags: windows-8, winrt-xaml, componentone

.sir I am developing a pdf viewer for this I used C!pdfViewer (from componentone.com).while running it giving me an dialogbox saying that

*"thanks for evaluating componentone studio for winRTxaml when you ready to purchase the product please 
visit at htttp://www.componentone.com/store"*

How to remove this dialog. if we keep this dialogbox likethis ,is there any problem to upload app into store

Comment: U r using a licensed product... So u need to purchase if u wish to use it further and uploading the app like this may get u in trouble...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to disable the component one dialog you need to buy component one studio.the free version will not have such option and hopely store won't accept such apps developed with free c1 studio

Answer (score 0):

Not to state the obvious, but have you purchased the product?  The [Component One page for Studio for WinRT XAML](http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/StudioWinRTXAML/) provides a free trial, but the production license appears to be $895.

As for acceptance into the Windows Store, no it would be rejected, likely with at least the following reason from the [Windows 8 app certification requirements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh694083.aspx).

```
1.2 Your app must be fully functional when the customer gets it from the Windows Store
```

I suspect too that the licensing for the component would also prohibit such use, but I haven not downloaded the trial to confirm.

Comment: I wish to put this app in to the store free of coast. It becomes too costly to me . can any one suggest me how to implement PdfViewer without using Component one tool

Comment: well, if you want to target 8.1 specifically there some additional PDF capability that might be what you need. I don't know of any specific free components, but there may be something on github/codeplex

Comment: how can I use 8.1pdf capability

Comment: I have not taken a look at this myself, but there is a [PDF Viewer sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/PDF-viewer-sample-85a4bb30) you can download. It would require installing Windows 8.1 Preview on a machine though and you wouldn't be able to publish until the Windows 8.1 store comes on line.

Answer (score 0):

May be this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8714500/1616443) helps you. 
Also take a look on this:[Reading PDF and XPS on your Windows 8 application using WinRT](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eternalcoding/archive/2013/04/15/reading-pdf-and-xps-on-your-windows-8-application-using-winrt.aspx)

But you need to know, that muPdf is GPL license.

Comment: i have done this but while uploding to store it saying that unsupported api is used what to do